# convert images to pdfs in subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of sub-folders with images in them. I am trying to recursively convert them into pdf files using the directory names as the pdf name. With the help of some Google searches I tried using this script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

for D in `find . -type d` do
  convert *.jpg ${PWD##*/}.pdf
end
```

It did not work. How can I get this to work?

Each folder has several `.JPG`s in it with a number 01-10 etc. Using `convert *.jpg name.pdf` converts all the images into one pdf file. I want to make a script to do this and for the PDF files to have the directory name.

I would also like the script to then grab the converted pdf and move it up a level into the parent directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `while` loop is more appropriate here. Try this:

```
find . -type d | while read d; do convert "${d}"/*.jpg ./"${d##*/}.pdf"; done
```

- `find` will return all directories in current directory.
- `while read d` will read each directory path into variable `$d`.
- `convert ${d}/*.jpg` performs the conversion on all .jpg images in directory `$d`.
- `./${d##*/}.pdf` replaces the whole directory path with just the directory name, appends `.pdf`, and ensures that PDF file is created in parent directory.

Comment: +1. Very nice regex replace of the extension. Maybe use `-iname` and also detect `jpeg` spelling?

Comment: @MartinKonecny Thanks! I like your suggestion for `-iname`, but looks like OP has updated the requirements =)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @savanto for the answer. I modified it a bit for my needs.

Read through the files in a directory's subdirectories. Convert one file type to a different file types. Name the file and save it to a directory (using OSX 10.10, terminal bash-3.2).

```
cd /parent_directory 
find . -type d | while read d; do mogrify -format png *.eps; done
find . -name '*.eps' -execdir mogrify -format png {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of savanto's answer that uses [img2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/), which is faster, lossless, and makes smaller file sizes than ImageMagick.

```
`find . -type d | while read d; do img2pdf "${d}"/*.jp2 --output ./"${d##*/}.pdf"; done`
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
find path/to/images -iname "*.jpg" | xargs -I %this convert %this %this.pdf
```

Very simple and clean!

Comment: This will convert each .jpg file into one .pdf file. The OP requires that _all_ .jpgs in each directory be converted into a _single_ pdf file, with the filename being the name of the directory.